# SharePoint 2007: Get the average of a list column and display it on a page

Tags: list, column

I have a list with a column filled with values from 0 to 10. I need to take the average of this column and display it (maybe rounded to 1 decimal place) on another page as a kind of big, bold, overview number, so some form of styling capability is required. What would be a good way to do this? I'm comfortable with SharePoint Designer 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a KPI, which is (fortunately!) a built-in function.
 you'll want to:

1. create a KPI list
2. create a KPI which contains the average of that column
3. add the webpart Dashboard > KPI Details to the display location

Here's Microsoft's page on KPIs in 2007: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-and-publish-key-performance-indicators-kpis-HA010080027.aspx There are some limits, but your use is simple enough that it shouldn't pose a problem.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I don't think I explained this quite right. I want to take ONLY the average (a single number) and display it on the page - not the rest of the list. Is this possible?

Comment: Updated answer. Hope this helps! KPIs are great. :)

Comment: Thank you! You were right in the first place too, I just didn't think about using KPIs in that way!